# Javascript client: Websocket not working?

Tags: javascript, events, websocket, client

I have a PHP websocket (Ratchet 13) and it works fine. I can connect to this ws via C# without any problem.
Now, i would like to connect to my websocket but with javascript, and in client side.

On my website, i would like the client to be connected to my websocket, and can send/received real-time data from the server.
Actually the connection success, but events are never called.
EDIT: After few mins the page is loaded, i have this in the console:
"WebSocket connection to 'ws://x:8080/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake timed out"

I have tried a lot of methods.

```
document.getElementById("value_ws").innerHTML = "coning";
//just some cheks 1

var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080"); 
//here i replace localhost by my IP otherwise it don't connect

ws.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("open");
};

ws.addEventListener('open', function (event) {
    ws.send('Hello Server!');
});

//both of theses events are never called
//i successfully receive the connection on my server ws console
//but when i send data, the event is never called   

document.getElementById("value_ws").innerHTML = "coned";
//just some cheks 2
```

If you have some tips you can give me, i take!
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:
problem was coming from my server that wasn't answering the handshake.

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

Answer (score -1):

Some browsers won't let you connect to unsecured websockets.  You would need to test with SSL/TLS enabled and "wss://localhost:8080" as your connection.

Comment: Love an explanation for down votes, it helps me know how to improve my answers, thanks.